# SELECT result in one table depeding of another SELECT in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table as follows:

```
`team_by_membre` (
  `id_team_by_membre` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_membre` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_team` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(2) NOT NULL COMMENT)
```

In this table, I am trying to make the list of all members that are part of a team managed by on one members (the manager). A team is managed by a member if level=1 (level=0 players). To clarify: in this table you have many players for many team and for each team one manager (level=1).

To find out the team managed by my manager:

```
SELECT rm.id_team
    FROM team_by_membre rm
    WHERE rm.id_membre = ?
    AND rm.level = '1'
```

(in my current table, one of the member is managing 3 teams)

But how do I make the list of all players (members) in this table who are part of a team managed by this manager? Any ideas?

Comment: all players in the same team has a unique id_team ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  team_by_membre
WHERE
  id_team IN (
    SELECT
      id_team
    FROM
      team_by_membre
    WHERE
      id_membre = ?
    AND
      level = 1
  );
```

Comment: seems like it could be done by joining the table to itself rather than a subquery, which is generally better...

Comment: @Kouber: in fact it is not working: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row (which is logical because one member can amange several teams)

Comment: So, which team members would you want to get in that situation?

Comment: @RobP, I disagree. Making a self join **might** be better in **some** situations, but on the other hand it is **always** worst to read and understand.

Comment: I want all team members that are part of teams managed by one manager

Comment: Ok, @Raphael_b, I edited the answer by changing `=` with an `IN`. That way you will get all the members from all the teams managed by the `id_membre` specified.

Comment: @KouberSaparev in my experience, nested subqueries always persist a temporary table, JOINs often don't so they perform much, much better. Depends on precise SQL implementation, of course. And I don't find them harder to read, they become quite natural. This case in particular shouldn't be hard.

Comment: @Kouber: It is working. Thanks for taking the time. I did not know the IN element; I will look at it to understand better. great day

Comment: @Raphael_b if you have time, compare to my answer below and see if execution time is any different? Thanks!

Comment: @RobP: so for the Kouber answer what will be the code with a JOIN??

Comment: @Raphael_b, I posted a proposed solution with JOIN as an answer just below.

Answer (score 1):

Using a join should be faster than a subquery and is pretty straightforward:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM team_by_membre t
JOIN team_by_membre mgr
WHERE t.id_team=mgr.id_team
AND mgr.level = 1
AND mgr.id_membre = ?
```

Comment: I run the two queries and it is the same in terms of time (but there are few entries in my table at the moment). Thanks for teaching me few tricks today